# Trying to figure out why my math will not add

Tags: java

I am currently working on a project for college which requires you to create a basic shopping menu. I am currently totaling my math by multiplying quantity of items by cost, but the total stays at zero. I created separate integers that store the cost of the item(ex: int hat = 32) and separate integers for quantity.( ex: quanHat = 0). For some reason, the quantity of items stays at zero even though I added a ++. anyone help me with this?

I have tried converting the integer to a string and back, but it does not seem to do anything.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Pirate Trading Post v3");
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    int eight = 8;
    int hat = 32;
    int patch = 2;
    int sword = 20;
    int map = 100;
    int shirt = 150;
    int test = -1;
    int quanEight = 0;
    int quanHat = 0;
    int quanPatch = 0;
    int quanSword = 0;
    int quanMap = 0;
    int quanShirt = 0;
    int total = ( quanEight * eight) + ( quanHat * hat) + ( quanPatch * patch) + ( quanSword * sword) + ( quanShirt * shirt) + ( quanMap * map);
    while (test != 0){
        System.out.println("Enter Item Code, ? or Q: ");
        String code = input.next();
        char ch = code.charAt(0);
        ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);

        if (ch == '?'){
            System.out.println("Valid Item codes are: 8 I H M S T.");
            System.out.println("Q to quit.");
        }
        else if (ch == 'Q'){
            test++;
            System.out.println("Pirate Trading Post");
            System.out.println(quanEight + " Genuine Piece Of Eight " + quanHat + " Pirate Hat " + quanPatch + " Eye Patch " + quanSword + " Sword " + quanMap + " Treasure Map " + quanShirt + " T-Shirt ");
            System.out.println("Total: " + total + " bits");

        }
        else if (ch == '8'){
            quanEight ++;

        }
        else if (ch == 'I'){
            quanHat++;
        }
        else if (ch == 'H'){
            quanPatch++;
        }    
        else if (ch == 'M'){
            quanSword++;
        }
        else if (ch == 'S'){
            quanMap++;
        }
        else if (ch == 'T'){
            quanShirt++;
        }

    }
```

The expected output should be cost of item multiplied by quantity, but the quantity will not store the value. I am thinking the value is not stored because it is a string, but I am not sure.

Comment: You're calculating `total` before the `while` loop even begins, where each `quan*` variable is `0`. Obviously, the value of `total` will not update by itself

Comment: move the calculation of `total` inside the loop.

Comment: `total = ( quanEight * eight) +...` is not *saving* an equation in the variable; it does the calculation, using the actual values, and stores the result (once) in the variable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the code calculated total , quanHat was 0. And so total was assigned the value 0.

During the while loop when quanHat is incremented, its value increments by 1.

But since total is not being updated or recalculated, it still shows 0.

you need to recalculate total in the if block of `else if (ch == 'Q')`

Comment: Thank you, I am very new to Java and that actually makes way more sense.